# Is there any way to read scientific notation as regular number PHPSpreadsheet?

Tags: excel, codeigniter-3, phpexcel

So i have this .csv file that contains order item id as scientific notation (cell's format is general)

[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5oS6.png)

And i tried to read the file using PHPSpreadsheet (im using codeigniter 3)

```
$upload_file = $_FILES['order_report']['name'];

$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv();

$spreadsheet = $reader->load($_FILES['order_report']['tmp_name']);

$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
```

When i tried to read and echo in php,

```
echo $sheet[1][0];
// result : 7,7736E+14
```

Is it possible the value to be shown as 777359539596902 like the formula bar says?

PS :

1. i've been tried convert it using number_format(), but the output is totally different number
2. I've also use `$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:A99')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0')` before the `$sheet` line but it still doesn't work

Thank you